# Order confirmation not received to the customer

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email, order-confirmation

1 (maybe a few more) specific customers are not receiving their order confirmations. This is odd since every other customer is not having this issue in any way.
Emails are received by both us and the customer, but when it comes to that 1 customer: No.

Comment: Have you checked your mail/smtp server log files?  Have you received any bounce (non-delivery report)email?  Anti-spam filters are the primary suspect IMHO.

Comment: I'm with @AnFi on this, spam seems like the first thing I'd check. You might also check routing issues, I've seen that in the past. Mail not getting delivered because it was being sent to the wrong place. Make sure to check your deliverability of the emails using a tool like https://www.mail-tester.com/.